# How to 'free' pages manually ref counted by get_page() for mmap?

Tags: linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, mmap

I am mapping multiple physically non-contiguous memory buffers to a single linear user space address.  I use vm_insert_page() and get_page().  I need to use get_page() on all allocated pages because only the very first page of a given buffer has a ref count > 0 and vm_insert_page() needs ref count to be > 0.
Supposedly (according to some post on the Net) I have to 'free' the pages for which I increment ref count by calling get_page() if no longer needed.  However, I'm not quite sure how to 'free' the pages. Do I need to keep track of each page struct returned by get_page() and then call a corresponding API to free the pages during unmapping?  It does not look like OS will do it for me automatically.  That is, after user process exists, ref counts on the pages stay unchanged and get incremented again on next mmap from user space.

My pseudo code is like this:

```
    allocate multiple phys non-contiguous memory buffers using calls to pci_alloc_consistent()
    for all 4K chunks in all buffers allocated above
         create a page struct using virt_to_page(phys_chunk_addr)
         // this is needed because only the very first page of a phys buffer
         // will have ref count > 0 which is needed by vm_insert_page()!
         increment page ref count by calling get_page()
         place the page in vma using vm_insert_page()
```

Thanks for any suggestions/pointers.
Dan.

Answer (score 1):

DMA-coherent memory might need architecture-specific caching flags, so you cannot just simply map it to userspace.

`pci_alloc_consistent` is deprecated.
For mapping a single contiguous memory block, use `dma_alloc_coherent` and `dma_mmap_coherent`.

---

If you aren't too much concerned about portability, you can avoid using `dma_alloc_coherent` altogether and use individual pages instead:

- allocate a bunch of pages with `alloc_page` (for PCI, you usually need `GFP_DMA32`);
- get the DMA address for each page with `dma_map_page`;
- map them to user space with `vm_insert_page`.

Please note that this is *not* a coherent DMA mapping but a streaming DMA mapping.
On x86, this does not matter, but on many other architectures, you would have to call the `dma_sync_`* functions at the appropriate time.

For an example of this in the kernel, see `drivers/firewire/core-iso.c`, `core-cdev.c`.

---

If you need to have multiple large and physically contiguous buffers mapped into one virtually contiguous area, you cannot use `dma_mmap_coherent`, so you have to do this the hard way:

1. Call `dma_alloc_coherent` as often as you need it;
2. in your `mmap` implementation, just set `vm_area_struct->vm_ops`;
3. in `vm_operations_struct.fault`, call `virt_to_page`, call `get_page`, and set `vm_fault->page` to the page.

For an example, see `sound/core/pcm_native.c`.

Comment: thanks for the reply.  The driver is for x86 only. pci_alloc_consistent maps to dma_alloc_coherent on our system. However, I'm still not clear how to 'free' pages whose ref count I increment with get_page().  unmap will take care of ref counts incremented by vm_insert_page but I'm supposed to take care of the ones incremented by me through get_page().  Any thoughts?

Comment: You don't need to bother with `get_page()`. Why are you not using `dma_mmap_coherent()`?

Comment: It looks like dma_mmap_coherent can map a single chunk of mem alloc'ed with dma_alloc_coherent. I need to map multiple chunks from multiple calls to dma_alloc_coherent to a single linear virt addr in user space. dma_alloc_coherent can alloc only 4MB chunks but I need a buffer of 5MB or more. I can easily handle dma-ing of multi-chunk buffers but I really need a process to see the chunks as a single linear address. Btw, the procedure that I described in my initial post works except that ref counts changed with get_page do not go down after unmap (i.e. process ends). It's a leak then.

Comment: You could call `dma_alloc_coherent` once for each page. But you are not supposed to do anything with the page of the returned buffer (`virt_to_page` will not work in many cases); this is what `dma_map_page` is for.

Comment: Thanks again for the info.  However, I don't think that what you suggested will work for me.  I need to dma ~5MB buffers (in 2 or 3 chunks max) to our device.  There is no support for scatter/gather dma. alloc_page will allocate only a single page so I would need to deal with many dma transfers per buffer which is not acceptable. I do not care about portability - both the driver and the device are custom and for in-house purposes.  So, if I do not need to be portable (i.e. x86 only) do you know of a safe way to map 2 big buffers to user space so they could be seen as a single linear address?